# I want to hide my files from windows 10 on Ubuntu 21

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, encryption, hidden-files

I dual boot Ubuntu 21 and windows 10, I don't want the systems to read or recognize each other in any way. My ubuntu partittion is on a external hard drive, my windows 10 partition is on the ssd in my computer, it came installed. When I am on ubuntu and I open the files app, I can see the files from Windows, they are read only but it still bugs me. When I am on windows, I just unplug the external hard drive, I obviosly don't have this option on ubuntu. I have looked into unmounting the ssd, powering off the ssd, and encrypting my windows files while I'm not using them. I don't know what option would be best. I would like to know if anyone with a similar situation can tell me how they solved this issue.

Comment: For Ubuntu, you could simply tell it to not mount the Windows partition on startup. Technically you would still be able to manually mount it, but it is probobly enough hidden-ness for you. For Windows, it shouldn't show the main Linux partition given that it is ext4, which Windows can't read. It might still show the boot partition, but that would be a Windows question.

Comment: Ubuntu has products that use the *year.month* format (eg. 20.04, 21.04, 21.10 etc) and products using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) but they differ in significant       ways (eg. not `apt` command exists in 20, only in *year.month* format products).  There is no Ubuntu 21 or *snap* only product for 2021 as they are produced only in *even* years.   Please be precise with details and don't make them up, as you maybe using a *fake* given none exist.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been already said in one of the comments, Windows should be not able to see the Linux partition, as it cannot read the ext4 filesystem that Linux uses by default. So there's nothing to do in this direction.

If you want Linux to be unable to see Windows files, you can uninstall the packages that provide NTFS filesystem support in Linux (NTFS is the filesystem Windows uses by default).

In my version of Ubuntu these are packages named `libntfs-3g883` and `ntfs-3g`. Removing the first one automatically removes the second. I guess the number at the end of first package name can be different in different Ubuntu versions. You can check the actual package names with the command:

```
dpkg-query -l | grep ntfs
```

Then type:

```
sudo apt remove libntfs-3g883
```

where of course you have to change the name `libntfs-3g883` if it's different on your system.

This should make Linux permanently unable to access any NTFS formatted partition (of course you can always reinstall these two packages to get NTFS support again). Note however that it will also make Linux unable to access USB flash drives and external HDD drives if they are factory-formatted, because they are formatted by default with NTFS filesystem. You will be unable to use them unless you reformat them to use ext4 filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Load the "Disks" application. Select the Windows partition you do not want to see. Right-click the partition and select "Edit mount options". Mark the checkbox "Show in user interface", and verify "Mount at system startup"  is unchecked.

That will cause the partition *not* to be shown anymore in your file manager.